# Ask a question about the object of a phrase

Tags: questions

In a test, they told us to rewrite sentences into questions. One case specified that the word to ask about is the object. I found difficulties transforming the following

> My mother taught me good manners.

into a question asking about the word `me`.

My answer was :

> Whose mother did teach good manners to?

Comment: This is a crazy question in a sense. The direct object of the first sentence is *me* but because of the *my* that is part of the subject, you can't really make a grammatical question from 'me' with the same interpretation. *Who did my mother teach good manners?* is a grammatical question but its answer can't really be "me".  If it was *Who did Bill's mother teach good manners* then that could be answered by "me".

Comment: Of course if the test thought that *good manners* was the object of the verb then the question should be *What did my mother teach me?*.  Since a common (but wrong) definition of "object" is "receiver of the action", this might have been what the test intended.

Comment: They explicitly said to ask about `me`

Comment: What you've tried to do I think, is, assuming that *me* is the object, but because *my* is also connected to *me* you've asked the question from the *my*.  This is smart because it avoids the problem I brought up in my first comment. So the only problem then, is that you haven't got the syntax quite right. It should be *Whose mother taught me good manners?* (But I suspect this is *not* what the test was looking for.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I am puzzled as to why you are reluctant to go with *Who did my mother teach good manners?*. It sounds just the sort of question which might be posed rhetorically.

Comment: If the question to be asked was about `manners` I'd say : `What (manners) did your mother teach you?` but that is just my interpretation for the question.

Comment: @WS2 No, I think it's exactly the right answer to the question as asked on the test. But typically we can't ask a question of the object when there is a coreferent pronoun inside the subject: compare *Who did his mother scold?* where we intend 'who' to be co-referent with 'his' versus *Whose mother scolded him?* (same intended interpretation).  The second sentence is definitely preferred, and the first is quite bad.

Comment: It's hard to tell what kinds of answers the test is assuming are correct. Unfortunately I don't think this kind of question is appropriate for this site.

Comment: @AlanMunn you know how ambiguous tests can be + I don't know any QA site other than this

Comment: "Whom did my mother teach good manners to?"  We need the object form of "who," which is "whom."  The preposition "to" is needed because "whom" is the indirect object.  In a ditransitive construction like "taught me lessons," the preposition gets omitted as the indirect object is placed immediately after the verb where the direct object normally goes, and the direct object immediately follows the indirect object (e.g., Ditransitive: "My mom made me cookies," vs., Standard: "My mom made cookies for me.")

Comment: Why not this? "Who did my mother teach good manners to?"

Comment: The stilted alternative that does not end the sentence with a preposition would be: "To whom did my mother teach good manners?"

Comment: It's "whom" because we use "whom" when it is serving as a pronoun for an object rather than a subject.  "Whom" is receiving the action of the verb "taught."  "Who" is only correct if "who" is performing the verb, so the question would have to ask, "Who is teaching?"  However, it's not.  It's asking, "Whom is being taught?"

Comment: It's quite common in spoken English for native speakers never to use "whom," to use "who" for everything.  As common as it is, however, it's not proper.  You can get away with it in an informal setting, but not in a formal setting and not in an English class.

Answer (score 1):

> My mother taught me good manners.

The original sentence has two objects: "me" and "good manners."  "Good manners" is the direct object.  "Me" is the indirect object.

Therefore, depending on which object you use, you can form two questions:

-What did my mother teach me?

-Whom did my mother teach good manners to? 
(To whom did my mother teach good manners?)